# What is the safest way that you could hash/encrypt a password?

Tags: passwords

What is the safest way that I could could hash/encrypt a password for my website?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There isn't really a safest way, but these things are the best tips I can offer:

- Use a one-directional hash, not an encryption, and compare hashed user input to stored hashes.
- Add a salt.  Instead of hashing 'password', which could easily be looked up in a dictionary of hashes, hash something like 'SALTpassword', where SALT is a string of characters you decide upon, and keep secret.
- Constantly review the system you end up using, keep an eye out for suddenly found vulnerabilities
- Enforce a policy of using decent passwords.

^ That should get you off to a good start, some reading up on password theory and opinion would also be a good idea.

Comment: Suggesting to do a simple hash of the concatenation of a salt and the password is rarely a good one; talking about "secret salts" is just confusing as well (salts are not secret, keys are).

Comment: Ok fair point.  What I would mean, for reference, is that the OP wouldn't be routinely revealing the salt they used.

Given the entry level of the question, I didn't think a deeper delve into password theory was a good move, but fair point that there is much more password hashing than just salting.

Comment: A salt should be globally unique for each password.  They should not be reused.  When you use a single piece of data that you hash with all passwords as you describe, it is more appropriately known as a pepper, and while it may be useful, it is not an adequate replacement for an actual salt, as it will cause identical passwords to produce identical hashes.

Answer (score 2):

"Safest" depends on the circumstances and context; there is no one-size-fits-all absolute answer.

However, there is a lot of accumulated knowledge on the subject. Basically, you want a *one-way* hashing process, so that someone who gets some read access to your server does not immediately obtains a usable copy of the passwords. The hashing process should also deter *parallel attacks* (that's what salt are used for) and be *configurably slow* (as slow as you can tolerate on your machine, as an attempt to slow down the attacker too).

Read [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/5411) first; it should answer most of your questions and provide links.